# MySQL - SUM of a group of time differences

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I want to sum all the time differences to show the total hours worked by a volunteer. Getting a result set of time differences is easy:

```
Select timediff(timeOut, timeIn) 
FROM volHours 
WHERE username = 'skolcz'
```

which gives the list of times by hours but then I want to sum it up to a grand total.

So if the result set is:

```
12:00:00
10:00:00
10:00:00
08:00:00
```

It would just total 40 hours.

This there a way to do something like:

```
SELECT SUM(Select timediff(timeOut,timeIn) 
FROM volHours 
WHERE username = 'skolcz') as totalHours
```

?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
Select  SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(timeOut, timeIn)))) AS totalhours
FROM volHours 
WHERE username = 'skolcz'
```

If not then maybe:

```
Select  SEC_TO_TIME(SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(timediff(timeOut, timeIn))) 
FROM volHours 
WHERE username = 'skolcz') as totalhours
```

Comment: u dont have to group by username since he already choosed skolcz

Comment: Looks almost right but I get '304538.000000' for an answer when the real data is 12:00:00
04:00:00
00:30:00
05:00:00
09:00:00
00:04:32
00:11:06

Answer (score 3):

You almost get the answer from **Matthew**, all you need to do is to add cast :

```
Select CAST(SUM(timediff(timeOut, timeIn)) as time) as totalhours
FROM volHours 
WHERE username = 'skolcz'
```

Comment: Didn't think of just trying to use cast - little more readable than my second iteration of TIME_TO_SEC --> SEC_TO_TIME. Thanks for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

try something like that

```
 Select SUM(timediff(timeOut, timeIn)) as total
 FROM volHours 
 WHERE username = 'skolcz'
```