# Calculating SUM of different datetime values

Tags: php, datetime, sum

I have several datetime queries. I need to get the SUM and display user side. How can I achieve this?

**queries**

```
    $sqlmon="SELECT * , TIMEDIFF(t.timeouthour, t.timeinhour) AS Duration 
    FROM timesheets t 
    WHERE employee_id='$session_myemployeeid' 
    AND timeinyear='$currentyear' 
    AND timeinmonth='$currentmonth' 
    AND timeinday='Monday' ";
    $resultmon=mysqli_query($db,$sqlmon);

    $sqltues="SELECT * , TIMEDIFF(t.timeouthour, t.timeinhour) AS Duration 
    FROM timesheets t WHERE employee_id='$session_myemployeeid' 
    AND timeinyear='$currentyear' 
    AND timeinmonth='$currentmonth' 
    AND timeinday='Tuesday' ";
    $resulttuesday=mysqli_query($db,$sqltues);
    [5 more...]
```

**I tried this but it does not work...**

```
Total :  <?=$timemonday['Duration']+$timetuesday['Duration'];?>
```

Comment: Soooooo.... `$timemonday['Duration']` contains what? A baloney? I mean a baloney + baloney is like double the amount of food. Or does it contain something else? Well.. it isn't that important to add that to the question anyways, right? I mean, here at SO we have the ability to snap our fingers and let magic do the rest.

Comment: @SebastianFarham You have answered your own no-value question, please delete this question as it will not benefit future SO readers who know how to Read The Manual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - SUM of a group of time differences](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790098/mysql-sum-of-a-group-of-time-differences)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790098/mysql-sum-of-a-group-of-time-differences) :

```
$sqlmon="SELECT *, SUM(TIMEDIFF(t.timeouthour, t.timeinhour)) 
AS Duration FROM timesheets t 
WHERE employee_id='$session_myemployeeid' 
AND timeinyear='$currentyear' 
AND timeinmonth='$currentmonth' 
AND timeinday='Monday' ";
$resultmon=mysqli_query($db,$sqlmon);
```